# Cannot access Matplotlib styles and 'plt.style' is empty

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm using python 3.9.1 and matplotlib version 3.4.3

I'm trying to show a graph plotted with matplotlib with one of the default styles (e.g. 'ggplot', or 'dark_background'), but python seems unable to find the styles. If I run the program without a style specified, I receive no errors and the program plots a graph in the default style. But when trying to run my program with the 'dark_background' style, python returns:

```
OSError: 'dark_background' not found in the style library and input is not a valid URL
or path; see `style.available` for list of available styles
```

As recommended by the error message, I tried to view the available styles with
`print(plt.style.available)`, but that just returned an empty list:
`[]`.

I've googled the output of `plt.style.available` from other people, and they seem to get a list of styles returned to them looking like this:

```
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn', 'seaborn-bright', 'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-dark', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-deep', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-notebook', 'seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-pastel', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

Whereas my output is still just `[]`.

Do I have to download the styles in addition to matplotlib? (which I downloaded through pip)
Am I calling on `plt.style` incorrectly?

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: can you try opening ``__init__.py`` in this directory ``C:\Users\(yourname)\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\matplotlib\style``? What's inside? this line? ``from .core import use, context, available, library, reload_library``?

Comment: Did you set the style with `plt.style.use("dark_background")` after importing `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Comment: @DavideMadrisan without actually importing ``matplotlib.pyplot`` it will just say ``NameError: name 'plt' is not defined``. So I assume OP already imported matplotlib

Comment: @Davide Madrisan yes, `plt.style.use("dark_background")` is called after matplotlib.pyplot is imported as 'plt'

Comment: @Karina I am running python on a mac osx system, so python is not found at quite that location, but I think that's irrelevant for the problem I'm having. the first line of .__init__.py in myplotlib/style is indeed `from .core import use, context, available, library, reload_library`.

Comment: did you try ``import matplotlib`` as well? I mean just ``matplotlib``, not ``matplotlib.pyplot``. I read it somewhere that matplotlib library need to be imported as well for some IDE (I forgot the exact wording and can't find the link anymore)

Comment: @Karina yes, the first 4 lines of my program are `import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from func import integrateGraph
plt.style.use('dark_background')` Sry, I'm relatively new to Stack Overflow, so I'm not sure how to make those newlines. `from func import integrateGraph` is just a second python file containing a function that I call on for my `main.py`.

Comment: That's really strange. I would suggest to try uninstall and reinstall matplotlib. If it still doesn't work then... I don't know, hope someone else can give you more insight.

Comment: @Karina just tried uninstalling matplotlib with `pip3 uninstall matplotlib` and the reinstalled it with `pip3 install matplotlib`, no luck. Thank you for your time though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to fix this. The problem was that I installed matplotlib using the `pip3 install matplotlib` command. When I used the `python3 -m pip install -U matplotlib` command, it seems to have resolved the issue. For some reason, the `plt.style` class does not seem to have any data, when I use the `pip3` installation method. Strange, but for anyone else having this problem, here you go!

Answer (score 2):

Should work with just the following commands:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.style.use("dark_background")
>>> print(plt.style.available)
['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn', 'seaborn-bright', 'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-dark', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-deep', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-notebook', 'seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-pastel', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

An empty list means the style files are not installed in your system, unless some custom [configuration](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files) is overwriting the default setup.

Comment: As I said before, `print(plt.style.available)` returns an empty list (`[]`), not `['Solarize_Light2', '_classic_test_patch', 'bmh', 'classic', 'dark_background', 'fast', 'fivethirtyeight', 'ggplot', 'grayscale', 'seaborn', 'seaborn-bright', 'seaborn-colorblind', 'seaborn-dark', 'seaborn-dark-palette', 'seaborn-darkgrid', 'seaborn-deep', 'seaborn-muted', 'seaborn-notebook', 'seaborn-paper', 'seaborn-pastel', 'seaborn-poster', 'seaborn-talk', 'seaborn-ticks', 'seaborn-white', 'seaborn-whitegrid', 'tableau-colorblind10']`

Comment: I found only one post telling that the cause was an older version of matplotib (version 2.0) that the one you are using. Are you sure of the version used? Maybe more than one version is installed (typically by pip/pip3)?

Comment: I just ran `pip show matplotlib` and `pip3 show matplotlib` and both show 3.4.3 as the current version. I installed matplotlib only yesterday, and a quick google search revealed, that 3.4.3 is indeed the newest version. Could it perhaps be a bug in the newest version? That seems unlikely, since it was released in August.

Comment: I do not think so because I've the same version installed (but on Linux) and the style commands work for me.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file)?

Comment: I just gave it a quick scan, but it doesn't seem to provide any insight into how I could solve this problem. As I have said before, I ran `print(plt.style.available)` and it returned me an empty list, not the one its supposed to.